# Creating a dynamic gridlist in VUEJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been lately interested in VueJs and looking for a simple way to create a dynamic gridlist in VUEJs for firstName, lastName and images per person.

Here is what i tried and its looks

```
 <v-subheader>myList</v-subheader>
<v-container fluid grid-list-sm>
    <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex v-for="item in customer.images" :key="item.id" xs4>
            <img  :src="item.image"  class="image" alt="lorem" width="50px" height="500px">
        </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
</v-container>


<script>

date()=>({
customer:{
id:"",
firstName:"",
lastName:"",
images:[], <----array od objects {id:"", image:""}
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this inside your v-container

```
<v-layout row wrap v-for="item in customer" :key="item.id">
    <v-layout row wrap>{{item.firstName + ' ' + item.lastName}}</v-layout>
    <v-flex v-for="pic in item.images" :key="pic.id" xs4>
        <img  :src="pic.image"  class="image" alt="lorem" width="50px" height="500px">
    </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```